# How to compare the difference of two sets of columns in a dataframe in an efficient and dynamic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 with the same set of columns. I merged 2 dfs together and want to

1. calculate the score diff for score1 and score2
2. see if the region column is the same.

The desired result would be having 'score1_diff', 'socre2_diff' and 'regional_diff' in the df_final (as shown in the attached picture). I created 'score1_diff', 'score2_diff' and 'regional_diff' columns in the df_final using the codes shown below.

However, in my read dataframe, I have over 30+ score columns and over 10+ region columns, there will be more score columns and region columns being added to the dataframe from time to time. In stead of creating these columns one by one, what would be an efficient or dynamic way to achieve the same result?

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

df1 = { 'Name':['George','Andrea','micheal','Ann',
            'maggie','Ravi','Xien','Jalpa'],
   'region':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
    'score1':[63,42,55,70,38,77,86,99],
    'score2':[45,74,44,89,69,49,72,98]}

df2 = { 'Name':['George','Andrea','micheal', 'Matt',
            'maggie','Ravi','Xien','Jalpa'],
   'region':['a','b','a','a','a','b','b','a'],
    'score1':[62,47,55,74,32,77,86,77],
    'score2':[45,78,44,89,66,49,72,73]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)

df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)

df_all = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',indicator=True, on='Name',suffixes=('_df1','_df2'))

df_final=df_all.copy()
df_final['score1_diff']=df_final['score1_df1']-df_final['score1_df2']
df_final['score2_diff']=df_final['score2_df1']-df_final['score2_df2']
df_final['regional_diff']=df_final['region_df1']==df_final['region_df2']
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking Jonathan's idea, below is the solution that works for me. The general idea is to create 2 df with all columns which have the suffix of _df1 and _df2, respectively, then replace the suffix with _diff in order to substract one df from another.

This approach is identical to Jonathan's solution only except I filter all columns with specific naming convention rather than using index with iloc.

```
df_final=df_all.copy()

num_current= [itm + '_df1' for itm in num_col]
num_previous =[itm + '_df2' for itm in num_col]


dfx = df_final[num_current]
dfx.columns = dfx.columns.str.replace('_df1', '_diff')

dfy = df_final[num_previous]
dfy.columns = dfy.columns.str.replace('_df2', '_diff')

df_diff = dfx - dfy

df_all = pd.concat([df_final, df_diff], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from `df_final=df_all.copy()`

```
df_final=df_all.copy()

#You can filter columns by the prefix; and remove the region column. Next, find the number of columns and rename them because they have to be the same name.

num_columns = len(df_final.filter(regex='_df1').iloc[:, 1:].columns)
cols = ['score{}_diff'.format(i) for i in range(1, 1 + num_columns)]

#get df1 and df2 -- NOTE: the order of the columns must be the same or you'll need to do that first. don't want score1 - score2, for instance. This assumes all columns are aligned correctly.

dfa = df_final.filter(regex='_df1').iloc[:, 1:]
dfa.columns=cols
dfb = df_final.filter(regex='_df2').iloc[:, 1:]
dfb.columns=cols

df_diff = dfa - dfb

df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df_diff], axis=1)
df_final['regional_diff']=df_final['region_df1']==df_final['region_df2']
df_final

      Name region_df1  score1_df1  score2_df1 region_df2  score1_df2  \
0   George          a      63.000      45.000          a      62.000
1   Andrea          a      42.000      74.000          b      47.000
2  micheal          a      55.000      44.000          a      55.000
3      Ann          a      70.000      89.000        NaN         NaN
4   maggie          b      38.000      69.000          a      32.000
5     Ravi          b      77.000      49.000          b      77.000
6     Xien          b      86.000      72.000          b      86.000
7    Jalpa          b      99.000      98.000          a      77.000
8     Matt        NaN         NaN         NaN          a      74.000

   score2_df2      _merge  score1_diff  score2_diff  regional_diff
0      45.000        both        1.000        0.000           True
1      78.000        both       -5.000       -4.000          False
2      44.000        both        0.000        0.000           True
3         NaN   left_only          NaN          NaN          False
4      66.000        both        6.000        3.000          False
5      49.000        both        0.000        0.000           True
6      72.000        both        0.000        0.000           True
7      73.000        both       22.000       25.000          False
8      89.000  right_only          NaN          NaN          False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan, this works amazingly well. I have a question, how can python tells these are numerical columns by running the code df_final.filter(regex='_df1').iloc[:, 1:].columns? I meant the .filter(reg='_df1' looks like it would filter all columns with suffix of '_df1', but how can i tells to filter numerical columns only? Thanks.

Comment: Review the iloc slice and how it works. In this 1: is dropping the region column. I considered adding prefixes rather than suffixes as you did so you can filter on df1_scor and it wouldn’t pick up regions.

Comment: Thanks. Then I have 2 follow up questions and appreciated for your advice. 1) How to add prefixes in my case? I need to full join df1 and df2, and the merge function has the suffixes parameter, but not prefixes. I could use rename function but wonder if there is a better approach. 2), I have more than 10 region columns, how to do this dynamically? Thanks Jonathan again.

Comment: Rename columns prior to merge and the leave out suffixes argument. Or get creative in the regex. You can open a new question if you need more help.

Comment: I can see the iloc retrieves rows based on index. However, the 'region' column is not always in position 0. But thanks for your guidance and ideas on this.